# How to point with one method to two different methods?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I have intention to point with the same procedure to two different procedures but I have not experienced programmer in Fortran so I need help.
This is my simple code:

```
module types

  type :: type_one
    integer, private :: a1,a2
   contains
    procedure, public :: f_data => set_data_a1
    procedure, public :: f_data => cal_data_a2
  end type type_one

  private :: set_data_a1,cal_data_a2 

contains

integer function set_data_a1(this)
  class(type_one) :: this
  this%a1 = 2
end function set_data_a1

integer function calc_data_a2(this)
  class(type_one) :: this
  this%a2 = this%a1 + 3
end function calc_data_a2

end module types

program types_pro
  implicit none
  type(type_one) :: type_obj
  type_obj%f_data()
end program types_pro
```

I got this error:
`There is already a procedure with binding name 'f_data' for the derived type 'type_one'  |

Is it possible to call both procedures at the same time with `type_obj%f_data()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic name, such as your `f_data`, allows calling procedures with different input signatures (rank, type, kind, and number of arguments) by the same name.  But, because they have the same argument signatures the compiler can't determine which of `calc_data_a1` and `calc_data_a2` to execute when your code makes a call to `f_data`.

Which leads me to a question for you: *How do you expect the compiler or code to behave ?  What do you want the compiler to do ?* (OK that was two questions.)

As a general rule, if you want the compiler to execute two procedures you have to make two calls.  You could, I suppose, have one procedure call the other if you want both to run when one is called.

If you want to wrap multiple functions behind the same name they have to have different input signatures so that the compiler can work out which one to call.

Obviously my earlier version of this answer wasn't explicit enough:

No, there is no way to write your code to execute two different procedures in response to a single call to one of them.  (Unless, that is, the one calls the other.)  Furthermore, it is unreasonable to expect a single (procedure) pointer to point, at any one time, at more than one target.

Comment: This code I simple code, just like I mentioned before. Firstly I want to call both with one call and I want first to set values to members and after that, I want to calculate values of other members( in this case it is only a1 for setting and a2 for calculating) - that is the order of executing. I know for the option to call one by one with two pointer procedures but...maybe with one pointer procedure? Is there a way?